# How do I create a movie in matlab using a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, video, plot, graph

I have a matrix (h) that I have formed in matlab that comes out as a 65x11, I'm looking to create a movie that displays plots of each column of the matrix. E.g. 65 frames

Comment: check out the `VideoWriter` function from MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i = 1:size(h,1)
    bar(h(i,:))
    ani(i) = getframe;
end
movie(ani)
```

if you want to create an animated .gif file, try

```
filename='myanimation.gif';

for i = 1:size(h,1)
    bar(h(i,:))
    ani = getframe;
    im=frame2im(ani);
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    if i == 1;
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append');
    end
end
```